HUGO content is not rendering
This is my first time using Hugo. My problem is that the content i put into the .md file is not showing on the targed page. I've checked the path and according to the HUGO-Docs it is all set up right.
├── content
│   ├── english
│   │   └── _index.md
│   ├── german
│   │   ├── home
│   │   │   ├── company.md
│   │   │   └── teaser.md
│   │   └── _index.md
│   └── _index.md
├── i18n
│   ├── de.toml
│   └── en.toml
├── layouts
│   ├── _default
│   │   ├── baseof.html
│   │   ├── list.html
│   │   └── single.html
│   ├── home
│   │   └── list.html
│   ├── partials
│   │   ├── common
│   │   │   ├── footer.html
│   │   │   ├── header.html
│   │   │   ├── head.html
│   │   │   └── scripts.html
│   │   ├── home
│   │   │   └── subnav.html
│   │   └── products
│   └── products

The home/list.html which overrides my baseof.html is set up like this:
{{ define "main" }}
    {{ partial "home/subnav.html" . }}
    {{ .Content }}
    {{ with .Site.GetPage "german/home/company" }}
            {{ .Content }}
        {{ end }}
{{ end }}

Neither the content from _index.md nor company.md is rendering. Not in browser and not in the public/index.html.
What am i missing out to render my content?

Hi, it would be helpful if you could reproduce the error on Codesandbox so it'd be easier to debug :)

Sadly im not getting any errors. Otherwise it would be easier for me.

It's hard to find the cause without seeing the source code of your site. It could be caused by many reason, such as incorrect configuration, templates...

You don't need to get errors to make a reproduction. The reproduction just makes it easier for others to help you debug.

Oh I see. I will remember it next time.  But after letting my failure rest over the weekend i just cleared my cache and voila the content is there...

Found the solution.
I just needed to clear the cache.
